# Getting the key of a dictionary from its hash in python?

Tags: python, object, dictionary, hash, graph

I have a graph class that uses an adjacency list to keep track of vertices and edges, as well as a vertex class with a predefined hash function that looks like the following:

```
class Vertex():
    def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name
    def __hash__(self):
         return hash(self.name)
```

Essentially, in my Graph class, I have a method called addVertex that takes in a vertex object and checks to see if it exists in the Graph already before adding it. If it does already exist, I want to return the object that is already in the graph, not the parameter I passed into the method. How would I go about implementing this?

```
class Graph():
    def __init__(self):
        self.adjList = {}

    def addVertex(vertex):
        try:
            self.adjList[vertex]
            return ???????????
        except:
            self.adjList[vertex] = {}
            return vertex
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a membership test:

```
if vertex in self.adjList:
```

The `dict.__contains__` implementation will then use the `__hash__` special method automatically.

Note that your `Vertex` class must also implement a `__eq__` equality method:

```
class Vertex():
    def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name
    def __hash__(self):
         return hash(self.name)
    def __eq__(self, other):
         if not isinstance(other, type(self)):
             return NotImplemented
         return self.name == other.name
```

Comment: Also, the parenthesis after `Vertex` are redundant. :P

Comment: Sure, but I try to echo the style the OP is using, where such the style doesn't matter that much.